# C++ program crashing (array and 2 pointer binsearch function)

Tags: c++, arrays, search, pointers, binary

When I run this program and enter a value to search for the program crashes(`exe` has stopped working, close program). Once when entering value 65, I got an infinite loop of Number not found Enter a value to search (-1 to quit):

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Search(int[], int * , int * );

int main()
{

  int i,KEY,num, array[] = {98,87,76,65,54};


  for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    cout << array[i] << " ";

  Search(array, &KEY, &num);

  cout << endl;
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void Search(int arr[5], int * current, int * numel)
{

  int low, high,search,N;

  cout << "\nWhat Number would you like to search for? (-1 to quit) : ";
  cin >> search;

  while(search!=-1)
  {
    low=0;
    high=N-1;
    while(low<=high)
    {
      *current=(low+high)/2;
      if (search > arr[*current])
        low=*current+1;
      else if(search<arr[*current])
        high=*current-1;
      else
        break;
    }
    if(arr[*current]==search)
      cout << "Number found at index " << *current << endl;
    else
      cout << "Number not found." << endl;
    cout << "Enter a value to search (-1 to quit) :";
  }
  return;
}
```

Comment: MY question is why is my code failing/crashing?

Comment: I suggest doing some research into the crash on your own. Start by using a debugger or inserting output statements to find where the crash occurs. Then work backwards from there to try to find where the problem could be.

Comment: thanks, seems that the array values aren't being passed to the function and/or if a value is not found the loop never ends.

Comment: What evidence do you have for claiming that "the array values aren't being passed to the function"?

Comment: never mind they are being passed, added: for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
            cout << arr[i] << " ";   in the function and the array values printed correctly.

Comment: Next check why the loop doesn't end if a value is not found.

Comment: ah!! the array wasn't in low to high order.

Comment: thanks for the guidance, program is running well.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, there's no way out of the main loop in `Search` if the number sought is not in the array.

Then you're using `high` before it's been given any value.

There may be other problems. How did you test this while you were developing it?

Answer (score 0):

`N` isn't initialized, so who knows what this statement:

```
high=N-1;
```

will do?

Comment: changed int low, high,search,N; to int low, high,search,N=5;

Comment: And did that change anything? The code probably has some other problems.  Stepping through with a debugger or throwing in some `printf()` statements (if you don't want to use a debugger for some reason) might provide some insight.

Comment: that stopped the crashing but now I have infinite loops for every search.